# Is there a symbol or name for a cyclic sum?

Tags: summation, notation, terminology, index-notation

I was wondering whether there is a symbol for a sum like for instance

$$x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_4 + x_4x_1$$

that I'd like to write as $$\sum_{??} x_i x_j$$ for instance, with $??$ being some kind of expression I'd like to find.

The idea being that you iterate through all "shifts" of the indices of $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$ (or $(1,2,3,4)$) in this case.

Conceptually you could maybe think of this as a conceptually similar thing to a discrete version to a contour integral $\oint$.

Comment: They're typically called [**cyclic sums**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum), and you write $\sum_\text{cyc}$ or something similar.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks, I updated the question accordingly!

Comment: You need to be clear whether you are dealing with the circular version, or with the symmetric version (where there are six terms here - add $x_1x^3+x_2x_4). I know you have specified circular, but the two are often confused.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thansk for the comment, yes I do indeed mean the circular version!

Comment: @Brian You could make that into an answer. I saw this and thought "I know the answer" only to see that you had it covered.

Comment: @MarkS. Done, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sums are typically called [**cyclic sums**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum), and a common notation is

$$
\sum_\text{cyc} x_1x_2 = x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + \cdots + x_{n-1}x_n + x_nx_1
$$

if there are $n$ elements in $\{x_i\}$.  Frequently, we see that there are variables $a, b, c$ (say), and we write something like

$$
\sum_\text{cyc} ab = ab + bc + ca
$$